# Best Way to store time (Only Time and Not date) in database

Tags: java, date, time, storing-data

I'm developing an application using Java (J2SE).
I need to store a Time in database (e.g. 16:30:12).
When I need to store date (Or date+time) I convert it to Unix timestamp and I store it as a `Long` number.
But When i need only the Time and not the Date and Time what is the best way to store it?
I'm Using `SQLite` and `MS Access` as DBMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ok to store time as time-in-milliseconds from null-date (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).
You will be able easily made compare operations on this long data field in the DB.

Answer (score 11):

A better way since `Java 8`, or by using the `Joda-Time` library in earlier versions:

Use the `LocalTime` class and extract the number of seconds since midnight. You can store this as a `three bytes number (0 to 86399)` in your database (instead of a eight bytes datetime).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("12:34:45");
int secondOfDay = time.toSecondOfDay();
// Save to database
```

To reverse:

```
// Get from database
LocalTime time = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(secondOfDay);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store as a normal `String`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String time = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Comment: Not a good idea if you plan on using the time in any sort of calculation.